# How to call Named Query

Tags: jpa, named-query

I wrote a named query in the entity class Voter

```
NamedQuery(name = "Voter.findvoter", query = "SELECT count(*) FROM Voter v WHERE v.voterID = :voterID" and where v.password= : password),
```

I want to call this named query and I also need to set voterID and password.

Can you help me. Thank you

Answer (score 38):

I assume you've missed the @ symbol on your NamedQuery annotation?

In the code, you'd call it like this:

```
List results = em.createNamedQuery("Voter.findvoter")
    .setParameter("voterID", "blah")
    .setParameter("password","blahblahblah")
    .getResultList();
```

Comment: how to find the element type of the list in order to iterate it?

Comment: Use a TypedQuery instead. em.createNamedQuery("Voter.findvoter",Voter.class);

Answer (score 4):

There are two obvious issues with your named query that would cause a problems:

- It is an annotation so it should be `@NamedQuery` not just `NamedQuery`
- Your query is currently:

`query = "SELECT count(*) FROM Voter v WHERE v.voterID = :voterID" and where v.password= : password`.

The problem is that you terminate your String after `:voterID`, instead of after `:password` and you have "where" twice and you have a space between ":" and "password". Your query should look like this:

`query = "SELECT count(*) FROM Voter v WHERE v.voterID = :voterID and v.password= :password"`

(I have just moved the " to the end and removed the second "where" and the space after the ":")

Answer (score 2):

The common steps are (named query or otherwise)

1. Create a query - em has five create methods.
2. Set the query up with parameters if needed - the query interface has these methods.
3. Execute the query - the query interface has 3 execution related methods.

with the above three steps you can run any JPA query.

Answer (score 1):

Actually brent is right your NameQuery should be something like this,

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Voter.findvoter", query = "SELECT count(*) FROM Voter v WHERE v.voterID = :voterID AND where v.password = :password")
@Entity
public class Voter implements Serializable{ ... }
```

and somewhere else you should try this one (which Dick has already said)

```
public class VoterFasade{
    public List<Voter> findVoter(long id,String password){
        List<Voter> results = em.createNamedQuery("Voter.findvoter")
            .setParameter("voterID", id)
            .setParameter("password",password)
            .getResultList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

then you could use it like

```
@Inject
VoterFasade voterFasade;

///
long id=12;
voterFasade.findVoter(id);
```

should actually working.(its an uncompiled code).

you could also do it with Repository, check the link below, part Repository Listing23.Example repository
[enter link description here](http://mrbool.com/apache-deltaspike-programmable-cdi/34626)